# Is this a good way to write a lexer?

Tags: c, compiler, lexical-analysis

I don't know whether if this is the right place to ask this.

I am semi-beginner in C. I always wanted to build my own Programming Language. Here I have built a lexical analyser completely myself. The lexer breaks the source code in tokens consisting of strings, characters, identifiers, constants and special symbols. It ignores single and multi-line comments too. And it can lexically analyse it's own code.

lexer.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SYMBOL(term) (term>=123&&term<=126)||(term>=33&&term<=47)||(term>=58&&term<=64)||(term>=91&&term<=96)
#define CAPALPHA(term) (term>='A'&&term<='Z')
#define LOWALPHA(term) (term>='a'&&term<='z')
#define ALPHA(term) ((CAPALPHA(term))||(LOWALPHA(term)))
#define WHITESPACE(term) ((term>=0&&term<=32)||term==127||term=='\n')
#define NUMBER(term) (term>='0'&&term<='9')
#define HEXNUMBER(term) ((term>='A'&&term<='f')||(term>='A'||term<='f'))

#define KEYWORD_COUNT 0

enum type {identifier,string,spsymbol,keyword,character,number,hexnumber};
char type2[25][25]={"identifier\0","string\0","symbol\0","keyword\0","character\0","number\0","hexnumber\0"};

enum keywords {regx,regy};
char keywords2[25][25]={"regx\0","regy\0"};

struct Tokens{ //Tokens structure
    char *t; //actual token
    int tlen; //token length
    int ttype; //token type
    int lineno; //token line no
    int keyword;
};

struct Tokens *token[100000];
int main(){
    char *input=malloc(100000*sizeof(char));
    FILE *fp = fopen("file", "r");
    FILE *of = fopen("lexout","w");
    char symbol;
    if(fp != NULL){
        int j=0;
        while(1)
        {   symbol = fgetc(fp);
            //printf("%c",symbol);
            if (symbol != EOF)
                input[j++]=symbol;
            else {
                input[j++]=symbol;
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }

    int c=-1;   //file current character
    int current_token=0; //current_token counter
    int line=1; //current line number

    int halt=0;
    while(1){
        if(halt) break;
        token[current_token]=(struct Tokens*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tokens)); //allocate memory for token structure
        token[current_token]->t=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*30); //allocate memory for token size

        int tokenTypeSet=0;
        int in=0;   //structure token counter

        while(1){
            c++;
            if(input[c]=='\n') line++;
            /*detect end of file*/
            if(input[c]=='%'&&input[c+1]=='E'&&input[c+2]=='O'&&input[c+3]=='F'&&input[c+4]=='%'){
                halt=1;
                break;
            }
            /*identify singleline comments*/
            if(input[c]=='/'&&input[c+1]=='/'){
                while(input[c+1]!='\n'){
                    c++;
                }
                continue;
            }
            /*identify multiline comments*/
            if(input[c]=='/'&&input[c+1]=='*'){
                c++;
                c++;
                while(input[c]!='*'&&input[c+1]!='/'){
                    if(input[c]=='\n'){
                        line++;
                    }
                    c++;
                }
                c++;
                continue;
            }
            /*identify string*/
            if(input[c]=='"'){
                //identify token type
                if(!tokenTypeSet){
                    token[current_token]->ttype=string;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                c++;
                while(1){
                    //newline
                    if(input[c]=='\n'){
                        c++;
                        line++;
                    }
                    //backslash escaped
                    if(input[c]=='\\'&&input[c+1]=='\\'){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //double-quote escaped
                    if(input[c]=='\\'&&input[c+1]=='"'){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //contiguous double-quotes
                    if(input[c]=='"'&&input[c+1]=='"'){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //terminate string
                    if(input[c]=='"'){
                        //c++;
                        break;
                    }
                    token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                    c++;
                }
                token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                break;
            }
            /*identify characters*/
            if(input[c]=='\''){
                //identify token type
                if(!tokenTypeSet){
                    token[current_token]->ttype=character;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                c++;
                while(1){
                    //backslash escaped
                    if(input[c]=='\\'&&input[c+1]=='\\'){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //sigle-quote escaped
                    if(input[c]=='\\'&&input[c+1]=='\''){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //contiguous single-quotes
                    if(input[c]=='\''&&input[c+1]=='\''){
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                        c++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    //terminate character
                    if(input[c]=='\''){
                        //c++;
                        break;
                    } 
                    token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                    c++;
                }
                token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                break;
            }
            /*mark hexnumbers*/
            if(!tokenTypeSet){
                if(input[c]=='0'&&(input[c+1]=='x'||input[c+1]=='X')){
                    token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                    c++;
                    token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                    c++;
                    token[current_token]->ttype=hexnumber;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                //continue;
            }
            /*read hex numbers*/
            if(token[current_token]->ttype==hexnumber){
                if(HEXNUMBER(input[c])||NUMBER(input[c])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                }
                if(WHITESPACE(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    //c++; //undo
                    break;
                }
                if(SYMBOL(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                if(!(HEXNUMBER(input[c+1])||NUMBER(input[c+1]))){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            /*read an alphabet or an underscore*/
            if(ALPHA(input[c])||input[c]=='_'){
                //identify token type
                if(!tokenTypeSet){
                    token[current_token]->ttype=identifier;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                //detect end of token
                if(WHITESPACE(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    //c++; //undo
                    break;
                }
                if((SYMBOL(input[c+1]))&&(input[c+1]!='_')){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            /*read a symbol*/
            if(SYMBOL(input[c])){
                if(!tokenTypeSet){
                    token[current_token]->ttype=spsymbol;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                //detect end of token
                if(WHITESPACE(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    //c++; //undo
                    break;
                }
                if(SYMBOL(input[c+1])||ALPHA(input[c+1])||NUMBER(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }
            /*read a number*/
            if(NUMBER(input[c])){
                //identify token type
                if(!tokenTypeSet){
                    token[current_token]->ttype=number;
                    tokenTypeSet=1;
                }
                token[current_token]->t[in++]=input[c];
                //detect end of token
                if(WHITESPACE(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    //c++; //undo
                    break;
                }
                if(!(NUMBER(input[c+1]))){
                    if(token[current_token]->ttype==identifier&&(ALPHA(input[c+1])||input[c+1]=='_')){
                        continue;
                    }
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }
                /*if(SYMBOL(input[c+1])||ALPHA(input[c+1])){
                    token[current_token]->t[in]='\0';
                    break;
                }*/
                continue;
            }
        }
        token[current_token]->lineno=line;
        current_token++;
    }

    //DEBUGGER
    //printf("Total nos of tokens = %d\n\n",current_token-1);
    fprintf(of,"Total nos of tokens = %d\n\n",current_token-1);
    for(int i=0;i<current_token-1;i++){
        //printf("%s:%s\n",type2[token[i]->ttype],token[i]->t);
        if(token[i]->ttype==identifier){
            for(int j=0;j<KEYWORD_COUNT;j++){
                if(strcmp(token[i]->t,keywords2[j])){
                    token[i]->ttype=keyword;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        fprintf(of,"lnos:%d,%s:%s\n",token[i]->lineno,type2[token[i]->ttype],token[i]->t);
    }
    printf("%s","***********************\n");
    //END OF LEXING
    return 0;
}
```

To test the lexer you need to create a source file named simply "file".
Inside "file" should be the source code followed by %EOF% string.
For example, file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int a = 5;
int b = a;
return 0;
}

%EOF%
```

Compile the program:

```
gcc lexer.c -o lexer.out -Wall
```

Output:

```
Total nos of tokens = 26

lnos:1,symbol:#
lnos:1,identifier:include
lnos:1,symbol:<
lnos:1,identifier:stdio
lnos:1,symbol:.
lnos:1,identifier:h
lnos:1,symbol:>
lnos:3,identifier:int
lnos:3,identifier:main
lnos:3,symbol:(
lnos:3,symbol:)
lnos:3,symbol:{
lnos:4,identifier:int
lnos:4,identifier:a
lnos:4,symbol:=
lnos:4,number:5
lnos:4,symbol:;
lnos:5,identifier:int
lnos:5,identifier:b
lnos:5,symbol:=
lnos:5,identifier:a
lnos:5,symbol:;
lnos:6,identifier:return
lnos:6,number:0
lnos:6,symbol:;
lnos:7,symbol:}
```

Where lnos is the line number the token appears in.
The Source code is well commented. Ask if anything is not clear.

Later I would use these tokens in Parsing phase.

All I am seeking is a little guidance.

I need to know

1. whether this is an efficient way to write a lexer.
2. Do you see any bad coding practice in the my code.
3. And if the code could be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Don't use `define` for function-like macros

There is no advantage and considerable disadvantages to using function-like macros.  They lack type-checking and tend to lead to bugs.  For example, if we use this:

```
c = '0';
SYMBOL(++c);
printf("%c\n", c);
```

We would see that it would print "5" because unlike a real function, the macro increments the value every time it's mentioned in the macro.

### Use more whitespace for readability

Lines like this:

```
if(input[c]=='%'&&input[c+1]=='E'&&input[c+2]=='O'&&input[c+3]=='F'&&input[c+4]=='%'){
```

are very hard to read because of the lack of whitespace.  It's much easier to read for most people when written like this:

```
if (input[c] == '%' && input[c + 1] == 'E' && input[c + 2] == 'O'
    && input[c + 3] == 'F' && input[c + 4] == '%') {
```

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

One of the macros in the code is this:

```
#define SYMBOL(term) (term>=123&&term<=126)||(term>=33&&term<=47)||(term>=58&&term<=64)||(term>=91&&term<=96)
```

However it's difficult to figure out what this means because of all the un-named numerical constants.  Better would be to d as you have done for the `LOWALPHA` macro and use character values directly.  Or even better, just use `ispunct()` as per the next suggestion.

### Use standard functions and facilities

Several of the macros attempt to duplicate functions that already exist.  Specifically [`isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) and many related functions are in `<ctype.h>`.

### Don't leak memory

This code calls `malloc` several places but never `free`.  This means that the code is leaking memory. It would be much better to get into the habit of using `free` for each call to `malloc` and then assuring that you don't leak memory.

### Check the return value of `malloc`

If the program runs out of memory, a call to `malloc` can fail.  The only indication for this is that the call will return a `NULL` pointer.  You should check for this and avoid dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (which typically causes a program crash).  If the program can't proceed without the memory, free any allocated memory and quit the program gracefully.

### Decompose your program into functions

All of the logic here is in `main` in one rather long and dense chunk of code.  It would be better to decompose this into separate functions.

### Use `bool` where appropriate

The `halt` flag is being used as a boolean variable.  If you `#include <stdbool.h>`, you can use a `bool` type to better signal how this is being used.

### Simplify your code

The code currently contains this:

```
if (fp != NULL) {
    int j = 0;
    while (1) {
        symbol = fgetc(fp);
        //printf("%c",symbol);
        if (symbol != EOF)
            input[j++] = symbol;
        else {
            input[j++] = symbol;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

That's much more complex and fragile than it needs to be.  It's fragile because there's nothing to prevent it from running beyond the allocated `input` buffer.  It's also more complex than it needs to be with multiple `while`, `if` and `else`.  It could be written instead like this:

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    puts("Cannot open input file");
    exit(1);
}
fgets(input, BUFFLEN, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Note also that I'm using `BUFFLEN` instead of a "magic number" as mentioned above.  Similarly, this code is more convoluted than it needs to be:

```
int halt = 0;
while (1) {
    if (halt)
        break;
    // more code
}
```

Write it like this instead:

```
bool halt = false;
while (!halt) {
```

### Don't use uninitialised memory

The code allocates memory for a `token`, but tests the contents of some of its fields before actually initializing it.  If you need it set to specific values, you should set it.  If zeroes are sufficient, use `calloc`.

### Don't clutter the code with useless things

In a number of cases we have code like this:

```
token[current_token]->t = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
```

However, there's no need to cast the value and `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be 1.  So the code could be written like this instead:

```
token[current_token]->t = malloc(MAX_TOKEN_LEN);
```

Again, we're avoiding "magic numbers" as mentioned earlier.

### Allow the user to specify input and output files

The file names are currently hardcoded which certainly greatly restricts the usefulness of the program.  Consider using `argc` and `argv` to allow the user to specify file names on the command line.  Also `file` is certainly a poor choice for a hardcoded file name since it doesn't tell one anything useful about what the file is expected to contain.

### Use a state machine

You might find it better to use a state machine to do this parsing.  See [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134888/parse-2d-matrix-2-versions/138019#138019) for an example of how to do this.